# Simple_form collection disable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want the value to disappear from the list after it is choosed. Why my solution is not working ? My form partial code:

```
= f.input :value, :collection => ['red', 'blue', 'green'], :disabled => :used_values
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with pure rails stack, you'll need js/jquery.

Write a js/jquery script with following code,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#selectBox").change(function(){
    $("#selectBox option[value='selected']").remove();
});
```

Comment: I should have added that this piece of code is in my nested form, where user is setting value for each color.